# How to close modal on bootstrap after function runs vue3 composition api

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5, vue-composition-api, bootstrap5-modal

I am running a vue3 web app and I have bootstrap 5 running perfectly after I installed it using `npm install bootstrap`.

I am running a function that works fine but I'd like the modal to be closed once the function is run. Below is my code:

```
    <template>    
    <p data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop3">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary my-2">Upload new property</a>
                  </p>
            <!-- Modal for property upload -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop3" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Add property to the list</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
        
                <div class="modal-body">
                <form @submit.prevent="saveToDatabase">
                  <label> Property Name</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    v-model="name"
                    required
                    placeholder="e.g. my house"
                  />
                  <label>Area</label>
                  <select v-model="area" required>
                    <option value="" selected disabled="">Select an option</option>
                    <option value="Island">Lagos Island</option>
                    <option value="Mainland">Lagos Mainland</option>
                  </select>
                  <label>Number of Beds</label>
                  <input type="number" v-model="beds" required placeholder="e.g. 4" />
                  <label>Price Per Night (NGN)</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    v-model="price"
                    required
                    placeholder="e.g. 120,000"
                  />
                 
                  <div class="progressBtns">
        
                    <button class="ui button fluid blue" @click="saveToDatabase">
                      Save
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { projectDatabase, projectAuth } from "../../firebase/config";

export default {
  setup() {
    
    const name = ref("");
    const beds = ref(0);
    const area = ref("");
    const price = ref("");
    


    const saveToDatabase = async () => {
     
      var send = Ref.push({
        name: name.value,
        area: area.value,
        bed: beds.value,
        price: price.value,
        
      });
      send;
      Ref.child(send.key).child("id").set(send.key);
     // close modal
    
    };

  

    return {
 
      name,
      area,
      price,
      beds,
     
      saveToDatabase,
      
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Below is my main.js :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import { projectAuth } from './firebase/config'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import './assets/main.css'
let app

projectAuth.onAuthStateChanged(()=>{
    if(!app){
        app =   createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
    }
})
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
```

Is there a way to programmatically close the modal once the saveToDatabase function is run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Get modal instance from DOM: [Modal.getInstance()](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#getinstance).
2. Use [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) to interact with DOM in Vue.

Generic example:

```html
<script>
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const modalRef = ref(null);
    const closeModal = () => Modal.getInstance(modalRef.value)?.hide();

    return { modalRef, closeModal }
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <p>...</p>
  <div ref="modalRef" class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop3">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks @tao this removes the modal content completely but then it leaves behind a static black screen that cannot be interacted with (the backdrop of the modal). Any way to dismiss the whole modal i.e in the same way that the close button with the data-bs-dismiss property works? Thank you so much.

Comment: Hmm..., well, it should work, according to their docs. Do you see any errors? My guess is there is something wrong with your implementation (with how you're instantiating bootstrap js). One option would be to try calling the `.dispose()` method, although that destroys the modal instance (and I'm not sure you can re-open it after that). If you need more help, consider creating a [mcve] which repros the issue you're having (on codesandbox.io or similar). Try to make it minimal (only add the bits relevant to the modal, not the entire project).

Comment: When I say minimal, I mean: don't bother with firebase details, any data or any other components you might have. The only thing we need is an empty app with an empty modal, only containing a button, calling a function which closes the modal programatically. By the way, a hacky way to do this (which would most likely work) would be to dispatch a `click` event to the modal footer's close button. All you need is a `ref` on it, to be able to reference it in your code. But that's a hack. I don't recommend it.

Comment: hmm that's interesting. I am new to vue (from angularjs) how do click events work with ref? I am going to try edit the code to create a minimal reproductible example

Comment: When the component mounts, if any element has `ref="myVar"` and `myVar` is a `ref()` returned by `setup()`, `myVar.value` is a reference to the DOM element (until component unmounts). So you can do  in a `closeModal` function: `myVar.value?.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));`

Comment: Ah right thanks! I think another issue i realised from the docs is that the generation of the `.modal-backdrop` class which does not go away when the `close modal` function you provided is run. The whole body element is in that class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243800/discussion-between-tao-and-deji-james).